# Duda sobre error tipo de datos y valores en Java

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo a programar y tengo el siguiente ejercicio. He de inicializar distintas variables con el tipo de dato que contenga el menor nº de bits para dicha variable, a un determinado valor que nos han dado. El caso es que me dan fallos dos tipos `long` y no sé por qué:

```
long milisegundosdesde1970 = 1298332800000; 
long poblacionmundial = 6775235741;
```

En el primero Netbeans me dice

> "integer number too large" y en el segundo "integer number too large.
>   May split declaration into a declaration and assignment".

No comprendo en el primero dónde fallo teniendo en cuenta que un tipo "long" es el tipo de dato más grande para un número entero. En cuanto al segundo, me pasa lo mismo pero además no comprendo lo de

> "May split declaration into a declaration and assignment"

Comment: Recomiendo buscar información sobre literales en Java , pasa lo mismo con su anterior pregunta, debe añadir el literal `L` si no lo tomará con enteros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que Java los literales de números enteros por defecto los trata como `int` y como el valor que has representado es mayor que el valor máximo para un `int` el compilador lanza ese error. Para solventar esto debe agregar la letra `L`, ej. `long num = 5468546L`, (da igual mayúscula o minúscula, lo que la minúscula se parece mucho al número 1 y puede traer confusiones a la hora de leer el código, por eso se recomienda utilizar la mayúscula). Lo mismo ocurre con los literales de números decimales, que por defecto son tratados como `double` por lo que si deseas asignarle valor a una variable de tipo `float`, utilizando un literal, debes agregar la letra `f` detrás, ej. `float decimal = 1524.23f` (igual que en el caso del `long` la letra puede ser mayúscula o minúscula).