# ¿Por qué este valor da error con este tipo de dato?

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo a programar. El caso es que tengo este código y me da error y no comprendo por qué:

long milisegundosdesde1970 = 1298332800000; 
  
 long poblacionmundial = 6775235741;

En ambas líneas Netbeans me dice que "integer number too large". El caso es que que yo sepa el tipo long abarca el valor de esta variable. ¿En qué estoy fallando? Muchas gracias, saludos :)

Comment: intenta con float o con double??

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Duda sobre error tipo de datos y valores en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137758/duda-sobre-error-tipo-de-datos-y-valores-en-java)  , además otra [pregunta relacionada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137748/duda-sobre-tipo-de-dato-float-en-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando usas literales en Java, se asumen ciertos tipos:

Si escribes `valor = 1298332800000;` se asume que 1298332800000 es un `integer`. Por tanto, si quieres que se guarde como un long, tienes que añadir una L al final, así :

```
valor = 1298332800000L;
```

Si escribes `valor = 123.05;` Java asume que es un `double`, nunca un `float`, necesitas añadir una f: `valor=123.05f;`

Si la transformación es de un tipo de menor "capacidad" a uno de mayor capacidad, entonces no hay problema, se considera un *casting* seguro:

long var= 123; //funciona

123 es un integer, que cabe en un long

Pero al revés no funciona:

```
float var=123.01; //no funciona, un double no cabe en un float, se pierde precisión

int valor= 1298L //no funciona
```

En esos casos el casting ha de ser explícito para dejar claro al compilador que sabes lo que estás haciendo:

```
byte hola= (byte) 128; //funciona, pero perderé datos, se guardará -128
```